# Can't seem to make the makemigration work

Tags: django-models

```
model.py:

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Departments(models.Model):
    DepartmentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    DepartmentName = models.CharField(max_length=500) 

class Employees(models.Model):
    EmployeesId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    EmployeesName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Department = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    DateOfJoining = models.DateField()
    PhotoFileName = models.CharField(max_length=500)     


cmd:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\tutorial\api\DjangoAPI>python manage.py makemigrations EmployeeApp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tutorial\api\DjangoAPI\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\tutorial\api\DjangoAPI\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Collins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Collins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Collins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Collins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Collins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 212, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\Collins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Employee'

C:\tutorial\api\DjangoAPI>
```

Im not sure why its not working because i found similar tutorials online and every other line was similar to mine. I always get the error; "No module named 'Employee' when i try running the server.

Thank you inadvance.

Comment: What's the name of the app where those models are? Did you add them in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: EmployeeApp. Yes i did.

Comment: Ok I see. Can you check if you wrote `Employee` instead of `EmployeeApp` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Alright. Lemme quickly check that.

Comment: Glad to help. Have fun!